# PHP: How can I send bulk/mass mail with Amazon Web Services?

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, newsletter, massmail

We want to use SES for sending Bulk email from our PHP mailing application. AWS sets a limit for sending 14 emails per second. Now I can build a script which posts a query  every second but it’s not really stable. Is there a combination available between Simple Queing Server and SES. So I can post the Email at once (example: HTML mail send to 10000 adresses) and AWS Processes every email.

Comment: Could you please describe what is unclear? or where you want me to be more specific?

Comment: We need more specific information.  How have you tried to send emails? Are you using a PHP library?Which one?  What does your code look like?  What kind of error messages are you getting from SES.  Right now the question is very broad and it would be difficult for someone to give you an answer.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its not that I need to post the code.. Because I am not getting any error messages or what so ever.. The SES part is working fine. I just need to know if there is a way to use SQS for sending mass mail by SES.